# How do you extend rbind for a data.frame subclass?

Tags: r, generics, methods, rbind, r-s3

My question is how do you extend `rbind()` to work with a `data.frame` subclass? I cannot seem to properly extend `rbind()` to work with even a very simple subclass. The following example demonstrates the issue:

**Subclass and method definition:**

```
new_df2 <- function(x, ...)
{
  stopifnot(is.data.frame(x))
  structure(x, class = c("df2", "data.frame"), author = "some user")
}

rbind.df2 <- function(..., deparse.level = 1)
{
  NextMethod()
}
```

I realize that extending `rbind()` is not necessary in this case, but my grand plan is to use `rbind.data.frame()` on a my subclass and then add a few additional checks/attributes to its result.

If you call the following, you get an error: `Error in NextMethod() : generic function not specified`.

**does not work:**

```
t1 <- data.frame(a = 1:12, b = month.abb)
t2 <- new_df2(t1)
rbind(t2, t2)
```

I also tried using `NextMethod(generic = "rbind")`, but in that case, you receive this error: `Error in NextMethod(generic = "rbind") : wrong value for .Method`.

**also does not work:**

```
rbind.df2 <- function(..., deparse.level = 1)
{
  NextMethod(generic = "rbind")
}

rbind(t2, t2)
```

I'm at wits end and guess at the limits of my understanding of subclasses/methods too. Thanks for any help.

Comment: You want the same behaviour as for data frames ? `rbind` / `rbind.data.frame` should both work.

Comment: @F.Privé The issue is that NextMethod("rbind") doesn't work when adding `rbind` function for a new class.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I will treat the `rbind()` specific case below, but I will first note we could generate additional examples showing that there are not problems generally with `NextMethod()` when the first argument is `...` (regarding the bounty request):

```
f <- function(..., b = 3) UseMethod("f")
f.a <- function(..., b = 3) { print("yes"); NextMethod() }
f.integer <- function(..., b = 4) sapply(list(...), "*", b)
x <- 1:10
class(x) <- c("a", class(x))
f(x)

[1] "yes"
      [,1]
 [1,]    4
 [2,]    8
 [3,]   12
 [4,]   16
 [5,]   20
 [6,]   24
 [7,]   28
 [8,]   32
 [9,]   36
[10,]   40

f(x, b = 5)

[1] "yes"
      [,1]
 [1,]    5
 [2,]   10
 [3,]   15
 [4,]   20
 [5,]   25
 [6,]   30
 [7,]   35
 [8,]   40
 [9,]   45
[10,]   50
```

#### So why doesn't rbind.df2 work?

As it turns out, `rbind()` and `cbind()` are not *normal* generics. First, they are *internally* generic; see the "Internal Generics" section [here](http://adv-r.had.co.nz/S3.html) from Hadley Wickham's old S3 page on Advanced R, or this excerpt from the current [Advanced R](http://adv-r.had.co.nz/OO-essentials.html):

> Some S3 generics, like [, sum(), and cbind(), don’t call UseMethod()
>   because they are implemented in C. Instead, they call the C functions
>   DispatchGroup() or DispatchOrEval().

This isn't quite enough to cause us trouble, as we can see using `sum()` as an example:

```
sum.a <- function(x, na.rm = FALSE) { print("yes"); NextMethod() } 
sum(x)

[1] "yes"
[1] 55
```

However, for `rbind` and `cbind` it's even weirder, as recognized in comments in the [source code](https://github.com/wch/r-source/blob/5a156a0865362bb8381dcd69ac335f5174a4f60c/src/main/bind.c) (starting around line 1025):

```
/* cbind(deparse.level, ...) and rbind(deparse.level, ...) : */
/* This is a special .Internal */
```

... (Some code omitted) ...

```
    /* Lazy evaluation and method dispatch based on argument types are
     * fundamentally incompatible notions.  The results here are
     * ghastly.
```

After that, some explanation of the dispatch rules are given, but so far I haven't been able to use that information to make `NextMethod()` work. In the use case given above, I would follow the advice of [F. Privé](https://stackoverflow.com/users/6103040/f-priv%c3%a9) from the comments and do this:

```
new_df2 <- function(x, ...)
{
    stopifnot(is.data.frame(x))
    structure(x, class = c("df2", "data.frame"))
}

rbind.df2 <- function(..., deparse.level = 1)
{
    print("yes") # Or whatever else you want/need to do
    base::rbind.data.frame(..., deparse.level = deparse.level)
}

t1 <- data.frame(a = 1:12, b = month.abb)
t2 <- new_df2(t1)
rbind(t2, t2)

[1] "yes"
    a   b
1   1 Jan
2   2 Feb
3   3 Mar
4   4 Apr
5   5 May
6   6 Jun
7   7 Jul
8   8 Aug
9   9 Sep
10 10 Oct
11 11 Nov
12 12 Dec
13  1 Jan
14  2 Feb
15  3 Mar
16  4 Apr
17  5 May
18  6 Jun
19  7 Jul
20  8 Aug
21  9 Sep
22 10 Oct
23 11 Nov
24 12 Dec
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. However I think this is incorrect. In your example you have `data.frame` as the first class. Which means when you call `rbind(t1, t2)` it calls `rbind.data.frame` (based on the first class). And as a result the `rbind.df2` is not called and "yes" string never printed.

Comment: @KarolisKoncevičius Thanks for the comment, I didn't catch that. Will investigate further, though please see edits regarding an additional example where for sure `NextMethod()` works with `...` as the first argument.

Comment: Thanks for looking into it. I think your example demonstrates that the error is not because of the ellipses (which was just a guess). No idea then why else would `rbind` stop working. But I would be really interested to learn how to use NextMethod with rbind properly. The error is about wrong ".Method" specification in my case. Maybe assigning the ".Method" manually is a possibility?

Comment: thanks for looking so deeply into this. I cannot accept the answer, as I am not the author of the question, but already gave it +1. Will wait a bit more to see if any other answers are added. But will gladly award the bounty to this answer (unless something elegant that makes NextMethod work comes along).

Answer (score 1):

The answer is to extend `rbind2`, not `rbind`. From the help page from `rbind2`:

"These are (S4) generic functions with default methods.

...

The main use of cbind2 (rbind2) is to be called recursively by cbind() (rbind()) when both of these requirements are met:

- There is at least one argument that is an S4 object, and
- S3 dispatch fails (see the Dispatch section under cbind)."

Comment: Thank you for the comment. But the question is about S3 generics, not S4. However I think it's nice to have it here as people looking for such answers will be informed about the possibility of using S4.

Comment: You can have S4 methods with S3 classes; just call `setOldClass("myClass")` first. This is the standard technique when you want to use S3 classes, but the simple S3 method dispatch does not meet your needs.

Comment: Sounds interesting. But I am a bit unsure at which point `setOldClass` should be called. Should I call it within the generic and have it switch to another generic of S4 class within it?

Comment: `setOldClass` is called as a standalone, at the same point you would call `setClass`. I.e. as early as possible, and before you define the method for `rbind2`.